# java sudoku why it doesnt show me the final result of sudoku

Tags: java, list, tree, a-star, sudoku

good evening, i tried to create an application who generate an initial sudoku and trying to complete it using A* algorithm, while executing, the initial state it shows, but when it starts to solve, the program closes without showing a result, why?

UPDATE EXPLANATION:
I created the initial sudoku and from it, I have to reach the final solution using linkedlists & Astar algorithm, the heuristic used here is minimum remaining values. I hope I explained the problem.

=============================

Console preview :

0 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 0

3 0 0 0 9 7 0 0 7

0 0 5 1 0 6 0 0 0

0 0 0 7 3 0 0 6 7

8 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0

0 5 9 0 0 0 6 2 9

0 0 0 0 9 5 1 8 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 7 0 9 0 7 0

=============================

```
package sudoku;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Sudoku extends JFrame implements Comparable<Object>
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int idp;
private int id;
private int[][] sudoku;
private int astar;
private LinkedList <Sudoku> sons ;
private boolean isFinished;
private boolean isValid;

public Sudoku()
{
    isValid = false;
    isFinished = false;
    idp = 0;
    id = 0;
    sudoku = new int[9][9];
    astar = 0;
    sons = new LinkedList<Sudoku>();
    init();
}

public Sudoku(int id,int[][] s)
{
    isValid = false;
    isFinished = false;
    idp = id;
    id = id+1;
    sudoku = s;
    astar = astar();
    sons = new LinkedList<Sudoku>();
}

public void init()
{
    int diff = 31;
    Random r = new Random();
    while(diff>0)
    {
        int x = r.nextInt(9);
        int y = r.nextInt(9);
        sudoku[x][y] = 1+ r.nextInt(9);
        astar += sudoku[x][y];
        diff--;
    }
    astar = 405 - astar;
}

public int astar()
{
    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            res += sudoku[i][j];
        }
    }
    res = 405-res;
    return res;
}

public void checkFinish()
{
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            if(sudoku[i][j]!=0)
            {
                isFinished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isFinished = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean isValidSudoku(int[][] sudoku) 
{
    if(isFinished)
    {
        if (sudoku == null || sudoku.length != 9 || sudoku[0].length != 9)
            return false;
        // check each column
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            boolean[] m = new boolean[9];
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
            {
                if (sudoku[i][j] != 0) 
                {
                    if (m[ (sudoku[i][j] - 1)]) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    m[ (sudoku[i][j] - 1)] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //check each row
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
        {
            boolean[] m = new boolean[9];
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
            {
                if (sudoku[i][j] != 0) 
                {
                    if (m[ (sudoku[i][j] - 1)]) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    m[ (sudoku[i][j] - 1)] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //check each 3*3 matrix
        for (int block = 0; block < 9; block++) 
        {
            boolean[] m = new boolean[9];
            for (int i = block / 3 * 3; i < block / 3 * 3 + 3; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = block % 3 * 3; j < block % 3 * 3 + 3; j++) 
                {
                    if (sudoku[i][j] != 0) 
                    {
                        if (m[(int) (sudoku[i][j] - 1)]) 
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        m[(int) (sudoku[i][j] - 1)] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("not finished yet");
    }
    return false;
}

public void checkSolution()
{
    if(isValidSudoku(sudoku))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
}

public void viewSolution()
{
    checkSolution();
    if(isValid)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku");
        JTextField[][] s = new JTextField[9][9];
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        for(int i =0;i<9;i++)
        {
            for(int j =0;j<9;j++)
            {
                s[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(sudoku[i][j]));
                s[i][j].setVisible(true);
                s[i][j].setSize(50, 50);
                s[i][j].setLocation(50*i, 50*j);
                frame.add(s[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void show()
{
    for(int i =0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0;j<9;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(sudoku[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public void solve(Sudoku sudoku)
{   
        for(int i  = 0;i<9;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j<9;j++)
            {
                int[][] ts = sudoku.getSudoku();
                if(ts[i][j]==0)
                {
                    for(int k=0;k<9;k++)
                    {
                        ts[i][j] = k+1;
                        Sudoku t = new Sudoku(id,ts);
                        sons.add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Iterator<Sudoku> iter = sons.iterator();
        Collections.sort(sons);
        while(iter.hasNext() && iter.next().getAstar()>0)
        {
            Sudoku temp = iter.next();
            temp.solve(temp);
        }

        checkFinish();
        if(sudoku.isFinished)
        {
            viewSolution();
        }
}

public int getIdp() 
{
    return idp;
}

public int getId() 
{
    return id;
}

public int[][] getSudoku() 
{
    return sudoku;
}

public int getAstar() 
{
    return astar;
}

public LinkedList<Sudoku> getSons() 
{
    return sons;
}

public int compareTo(Object other) 
{
    Sudoku temp = (Sudoku)other;
    if (this.astar < temp.astar)
        return 1;
    else if (this.astar > temp.astar)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0; 
}
}
```

==================================================

```
package sudoku;

public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Sudoku s = new Sudoku();
    s.show();
    s.solve(s);
}

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: i will update the explanation

Comment: @RobinhoodVanpersie Yelling at people doesn't help

Comment: @talex, I did my effort and i'm stuck, i couldn't move further

Comment: Does it throw any errors when closing?

Comment: nothing, empty console, i thought i did a frame to show the final result but nothing appears

Comment: Did you tried debugger?

Comment: When I run it it print square full of numbers.

Comment: never used eclipse debugger ever, i usually check my code manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your show() method is overriding the java.awt.Window.show() method. You need to call super.show() as the first line in that method. So your new method would be:

```
public void show()
{
    super.show();//Call to super class to let it paint the window
    for(int i =0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0;j<9;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(sudoku[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

After I made this change it shows the JFrame. I also made the JFrame centered and fixed it so that when the X is clicked the application closes. Below is my modified Main class. The JFrame doesn't show anything but a gray background. Looks like you still have some work to do to render your components. I hope this gets you closer to your solution.

```
package sudoku;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Sudoku s = new Sudoku();
    s.setSize(400, 400);

    //Center the JFrame
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    s.setLocation(dim.width/2-s.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-s.getSize().height/2);

    //Close application when the user clicks the X
    s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    s.show();
    s.solve(s);
}
```

Comment: i will try to move further in solving the puzzle, thanks for helping in showing the frame